# "Lunar tropics"

Tags: the-moon

The tropics is region of the Earth in which the Sun could be directly overhead.  What is the corresponding region for the Moon?  Is it the same or slightly larger?

I live in the UK and hence have to travel quite far to see the Sun directly overhead.  If I am content to see the Moon directly overhead, would my trip be much shorter?

My experience suggests so.  Once long ago, I travelled to India without flying.  I "saw" the Moon directly overhead while in Iran and hence not yet in the Tropics.  However, I had no way to accurately measure this and I may have mistaken the usually high (for me) Moon for being exactly overhead.

Comment: I originally read this question title to mean "where on the moon can the Sun be directly overhead".

Comment: Not my question but it would also be interesting.  A rather long trip to go to see it though.  I was not sure of the correct term for what I wanted hence the quotation marks which were intended to indicate that it was only my guess of the appropriate term.

Comment: Verne put the giant cannon of [From the Earth to the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_the_Earth_to_the_Moon) south of the 28th parallel so it could be vertical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The orbital inclination of the Moon is 5.1°, which means it can be that amount above or below the ecliptic. That means it can theoretically reach a declination of 23.4° + 5.1° = 28.5° (North and South), so [Chabahar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chabahar), in the south of Iran, lying 25° North of the equator, is within the "lunar tropics".

This will not happen every month or even year; sometimes, the orbital inclination of the Moon (around the Earth) and the Earth (around the Sun) cancel out and the maximum declination will be 23.4° - 5.1° = 18.3°. This is a [minor lunar standstill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_standstill). One could say that at that moment, the "lunar tropics" are smaller than the "solar tropics". The last minor lunar standstill happened in October 2015; we're slowly moving towards a major standstill which will occur in April 2025.

Comment: I did not go to the very south of Iran.  As well as Tehran, I went to Isfahan (32°38′N 51°39′E) and Zahedan (29°29′N 60°51′E).  So, it seems that I cannot have seen the Moon directly overhead but I might have been lucky and seen it close.  The time that I saw this "high moon" was during a rest stop on the bus trip between those cities, I guess that the road may have dipped skightly south but probably not.  Certainly, it was much higher than I ever see it here in the UK.

Comment: I saw the term "lunar standstill" first only just now while researching this question.  I'll read up on it.

Comment: After some reading, it seems that I was mistaken.  My trip was not near a major standstill, it 5.5 years before one.  So, the Moon was maybe much higher than I was used to but not directly overhead.