# Polar circle for the moon

Tags: the-moon

The polar circle is the limit for how far north or south the sun will shine 24h. But is there a similar limit for the moon?

Comment: Sort of, roughly 5 degrees further from the pole, so around 61 degees lattitude. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_standstill and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27232/lunar-tropics

Comment: You may also find the answer to [How does the Moon move in the “night” sky as seen from the poles?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27747/7982) interesting.